# Kibana 4 behind nginx and ssl

Tags: nginx, elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4

I have successfully installed kibana3 with ssl behind nginx but now I want to add kibana4 too.

My nginx conf so far:

```
server {
  listen                *:443;

  server_name           my.host.com;
  access_log            /var/log/nginx/my.host.com.log;

  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;

  auth_basic "Restricted";
  auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/conf.d/kibanaAuth;


  location / {
    root  /usr/share/nginx/kibana3;
    index  index.html  index.htm;
  }

  location /kibana4.* {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5601;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }
```

I'm getting 404's when accessing `https://my.host.com/kibana4` and kibana4 service is running.

error log:

`79.167.46.61 - host [28/Oct/2015:08:25:09 +0000] "GET /kibana4 HTTP/1.1" 404 570 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.80 Safari/537.36"
79.167.46.61 - host [28/Oct/2015:08:25:09 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 1150 "https://my.host.com/kibana4" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.80 Safari/537.36"`

In kibana configuration I only changed es host location.

---

**Update:**
When changed `/kibana.*` to `/kibana` nginx returned `502 error`while kibana is running.

error:
`*2 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 79.167.46.61, server: my.host.com, request: "GET /kibana4 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5601/kibana4", host: "my.host.com"`

Comment: @matagus no no that's kibana3 which runs fine, the problem is with `/kibana4` which is a service listening on port:5601

Comment: ok... what does the error log says?

Comment: Change `location /kibana4.*` to `location /kibana4`, i.e remove the `.*`

Comment: @elssar good point, at least now it's a 502 error :)

Comment: You need to rewrite the request to remove `/kibana4` from the url